# Show the answer author in suggested edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, answers, suggested-edits

Today, I was going through a suggested edit and found that it was shortening the code (something that we don't allow on our site (Code Golf)). However, when I tried to reject it, it had already been accepted by another user. Thus, I overrode it, thinking that it was someone who isn't aware of this policy accepting the edit, and went to go leave a note for that reviewer. However, after going to the post itself, I realized the reviewer was the post author themselves, and if they accept it, then it's allowed. (I understand this may be a bit strange, but that's the nature of our site - you can't improve other people's code by editing it, you are supposed to suggest golfs and other improvements in comments).

---

When reviewing a suggested edit, we can see the question title, score, answer count, and author, and their reputation and badge count, when the question was asked, its view count, the edit comment, the answer content and score, the editor name, and comments.

However, we can't actually see the author of the answer itself. Given how much other information there is, it doesn't really make sense that this bit of information *isn't* there.

I could've avoided this confusion and I will be more diligent in the future, but I mistakenly thought the *question* author was the OP of the post being edited, because that was the name listed with the post.

**TL;DR** - can suggested edit review tasks also show the answer author?

Comment: Meh, that's what happens when you try to fix something that isn't broken. The answer author [used to be displayed in the old design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsTj5.png).

Comment: @41686d6564 I think they've been deliberately reducing the amount of information that reviewers get about authors (for example delegating suggester info to the tiny line at the bottom, removing)

Comment: @OlegValter Yet, they show the entire card of the _question_ author on top of the review _on an answer_. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @41686d6564 yup, no idea for what reason do we as reviewers need to know who wrote the question over who proposed the edit (or wrote the answer for that matter)...

Comment: Odd the question author is shown for reviews of both questions and answers, along with who proposed the edit; but the author of an edited answer isn't shown (you have to click-thru): Q-Edit https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78441  A-Edit https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78422

Comment: @rob that feels inconsistent. Regardless we could at least see if the the original author of the post was involved? Even if they aren't named?