# Make it easier to identify if the review task is a question or an answer in the review history

Tags: feature-request, review-history

In the review history page of a user, it is not possible to identify if the review task was for a question or an answer until one clicks the link of the task.

Please make it easier to identify if the review task is a question or an answer. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: If you're going to make a suggestion you really should posit why it's a good idea. Why do we need to know it's a question or an answer upfront?

Comment: It is a nice-to-have feature.

Comment: because? That still doesn't explain why you think we'd want it.

Comment: It takes a lot of time to analyse how many answers and questions I have reviewed. This feature may help me.

Comment: I have to open each link of the review task and then identify if it is a question or an answer. That takes time. Regarding why I want the feature, is there any other simpler way to identify the number of questions and answers I have reviewed? If yes, please let me know. If no, that's the reason I want this feature.

Comment: OK why is it important to identify or count the number of questions and answers separately?

Comment: When we can have separate section for a user's questions and answers instead of combining them as user's posts, why can't we have a separate section for a user's question reviews and answer reviews?

Comment: @RobertLongson Just yesterday, I needed to find answers in the Suggested Edit review queue's history to verify something about [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366379/348196). I had to hover over the items in the table one by one and look at the link to see if it's an answer or a question. I'd say, there are indeed good use cases for this.

Comment: @41686d6564 you could've used SEDE for that. It doesn't work for the OP because  SEDE strips information about the users doing the reviews.

Comment: @Glorfindel I could've but I only needed to find a couple of answers. Hovering over the links was much faster than going to SEDE and writing a query. Well, maybe for _you_, SEDE would've been faster ;) Anyway, if an indicator is added per this request, neither of those would be needed.